# Error of http port:80 on opening website

Tags: apache, port

When I open my web on internet my web open but it shows this error:

```
**Index of /**

     cgi-bin/

Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at mydomain.net Port 80
```

What can I do I don't understand what is the problem? Is my website hacked, or is it my webhost server problem? Is all data deleted? What is port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your content has been deleted, or your web host has a configuration problem.

To find out which, use `ftp` (or whatever way you normally use to upload files) to log in and check if your files are still there.

`ftp` is used by most web hosts, and it's an insecure protocol so it's quite easy to grab the password for someone that has access to the same WIFi hotspot or any network equipment between you and the web host. I'd change passwords while you're at it.

Comment: My Files are still there

Comment: @deemi.exe If the files are still there (in public_html or whatever the public directory is called at your provider), but cgi-bin is the only thing showing up in the listing, it sounds like you'll need to contact your hosting provider to ask why they're not showing up. Sounds like it may be a configuration problem.

Comment: Is there folder permission issue or should i call to my host provider

Comment: If you get a file listing, it does not sound like a permission issue, the server would normally return a `403 Forbidden` error if that's the case.